# Customizing my alertbox using inflater doesn't work

Tags: android

I am a beginner to Android Studio. I am working on my android quiz application for our school activity. The code shown below is what i have to check if my answer in my true or false question is correct. I want to display a custom AlertBox, but it doesn't work.The app stops and goes back its previous activity. I tried to change it to the default alertbox. It works fine, but if I add inflater it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

```
  public void checkAnswer(View view) {

            // Get pushed button.
            Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
            String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

            TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) 
            view.findViewById(R.id.image);
            TextView laman = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.laman);

            if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
                // Correct!
                startService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, tamamusic.class));
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
                title.setText("Magaling!");
                laman.setText("Tama ang iyong sagot! ");
                rightAnswerCount++;

            } else {
                // Wrong...
                startService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, malimusic.class));
                title.setText("Magsanay pa!");
                laman.setText("Mali ang iyong sagot! ");
                imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.wrong);
            }

            // Create Dialog.

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, (ViewGroup) view, false);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new 
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                        // Show Result.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), roxasresult.class);
                        intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        quizCount++;
                        showNextQuiz();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setView(v);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.show();
        }
```

Here is the code that is written before the codes above.

```
 public class roxasquiz extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView timer;
private TextView countLabel;
private TextView questionLabel;
private Button answerBtn1;
private Button answerBtn2;

private String rightAnswer;
private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
private int quizCount = 1;
static final private int QUIZ_COUNT = 3;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData[][] = {
        // {"Question", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"}
        {"Sa loob ng 10 taon naging speaker of the House si Manuel Roxas. ", 
   "MALI", "TAMA", },
        {"Nagtapos ng abogasya si Manuel Roxas sa University of Santo 
    Tomas.", "MALI", "TAMA",},
        {"Sa lalawigan ng Tarlac ipinanganak si Manuel Roxas. ", "MALI", 
   "TAMA", },


};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rizaltruefalse);
    stopService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, BackgroundSoundService.class));
    countLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
    questionLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
    answerBtn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn1);
    answerBtn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtn2);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerlabel);
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerlabel);

    startService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, timer.class));

    new CountDownTimer(61000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText("Oras:" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("TAPOS NA!");
            timeUp();

        }

        private void timeUp() {
            stopService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, tamamusic.class));
            stopService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, malimusic.class));
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    roxasquiz.this);
           builder.setTitle("Tapos na ang oras!")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, 
     int id) {
                                    Intent intent = new 
   Intent(getApplicationContext(), roxasresult.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", 
   rightAnswerCount);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }
    }.start();

    // Create quizArray from quizData.
    for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {
        // Prepare array.
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]);  // Country
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]);  // Right Answer
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]);  // Choice1


        // Add tmpArray to quizArray.
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);
    }

    showNextQuiz();

}

public void showNextQuiz() {

    // Update quizCountLabel.
    countLabel.setText("Tanong " + quizCount);

    // Generate random number between 0 and 14 (quizArray's size - 1).
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

    // Pick one quiz set.
    ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

    // Set question and right answer.
    // Array format: {"Country", "Right Answer", "Choice1", "Choice2", 
 "Choice3"}
    questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
    rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

    // Remove "Country" from quiz and Shuffle choices.
    quiz.remove(0);

    answerBtn1.setText("TAMA");
    answerBtn2.setText("MALI");

    quizArray.remove(randomNum);

}
```

This is my code to make it a default alertbox and it works fine.

```
 Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

    String alertTitle;
    String laman;

    if (btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {
        // Correct!
        startService(new Intent(roxasquiz.this, tamamusic.class));

        alertTitle = "Magaling!";
        laman = "Tama ang iyong sagot";

        rightAnswerCount++;

    } else {
        // Wrong...
       alertTitle = "Magsanay pa!";
        laman = "Mali ang iyong sagot";
    }

    // Create Dialog.
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage(laman);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                // Show Result.
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), roxasresult.class);
                intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                quizCount++;
                showNextQuiz();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: It will help people if you explain exactly what "doesn't work" e.g. no alert is shown at all _or_ it shows the wrong content in the alert

Also, explain what you tried to solve this problem, e.g.  what do you see when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: This line `Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());` Tells me that `view` is the Button so you should simply do a cast, ie `Button answerBtn = (Button) view;` except the next few lines tell me that `view` is a layout `TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);` Which is it?

Comment: the TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title); is what i have assigned for the title of my custom alertbox

Comment: Yes, view is for the buttons.  In my xml, i have this code android:onClick="checkAnswer" for both of the buttons

Comment: The app closes and goes back to its previous activity using the inflater

Comment: Read this https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html, debug your app, and at minimum share the stacktrace and specific line number where your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);


AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: null value doesnt work for me. thank you for your answer :)